# If/Else Validation in Android App?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-studio

I am creating a simple App for a college prep assignment using android studio

I have been able to develop most of the App but I need help with the following function:

- Make sure all fields are entered

if yes (do maths calculation)

if no (do no maths calculation, have a popup returning "missing field")

like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Missing Value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I was thinking an If/Else statement but I am new to all this and cant seem to get it to work

Heres the all the java code I have showing the maths functions etc

```
    //Inside the OnCreate
    //Linking the Variables
    Numet0 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Numet1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Numet2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    //Creating Function On Button 1
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Double Num0 = Double.parseDouble(Numet0.getText().toString());
            Double Num1 = Double.parseDouble(Numet1.getText().toString());
            Double Num2 = Double.parseDouble(Numet2.getText().toString());
            //Result Output
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet0.getText()) ||TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet1.getText())|| TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet2.getText())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                result = ((Num0 - Num1) / Num2);
                tv.setText("Your monthly payment = €" + result);
                //Popup After Button Press
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Heres the error I get when I try the above if/else statement

```
02-21 23:37:27.564 2310-2310/com.nci.caprep E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.nci.caprep, PID: 2310
                                                              java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                  at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                  at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                  at com.nci.caprep.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: we dont get it, what is the problem/error?

Comment: Why won't it work? What's happening?

You should check the user has inputted something in the EditText before parsing it

Comment: @AndrewSeymour I have updated, with what I tryed and the error log when it crashes the app

Comment: @Xoce I have updated, with what I tryed and the error log when it crashes the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `public void onClick(View v)` you could check

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet0.getText()) ||TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet1.getText())||TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet2.getText())) {
    // show your Toast
    return;
}
// If above condition is not true
// use your parseDouble method to get Double value, because at this point you know that NumetX.getText().toString() won't throw NPE
// update your TextView or any other UI component (No need to show Toast of error here)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: My App just crash when I hit the calculate button, I have updated my question with the new code am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Nvm figured it out had the double variables int he wrong place

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you can go about this:

1.) If one of the EditText values is equal to a blank string, then show the popup

```
if(Numet0.getText() == "" || Numet1.getText() == "" || Numet2.getText() == "") {
    //show message
}
else {
    //calculation
}
```

2.)Check the value beforehand and use a boolean to track if one of the edittexts are empty

```
boolean emptyEditText = false;
//onCreate
//inside onClick method
if(Numet0.getText() == "" || Numet1.getText() == "" || Numet2.getText() == "") {
    emptyEditText = true;
}
else {
    emptyEditText = false;
}
if(emptyEditText) {
    //show message
}
else {
    //calculate
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Numet0.getText() == ""` or even better `TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet0.getText())`

Comment: I meant Numet0.getText() == "". Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: But user might change values in Numet0 - 2 `EditText` views. Then (2) you have mentioned would fail, because you are setting your `emptyEditText` boolean value in `onCreate`.

Comment: That is true. I made an adjustment, but it would be redundant to use a boolean in this case I guess. Number one is the best suggestion in my opinion, or in the other answer using the TextUtils.isEmpty(Numet0-2.getText()).